# monitor mutal to PC and MacBook, shows only Mac

Tags: windows-7, mac, windows-8, multiple-monitors, dvi

I have a monitor that connected to my PC (win8, VGA)

and to my MacBook (DisplayPort to DVI).

I set it from my PC to display the Mac only (one monitor).

When I unplug the Mac from the display port, it doesn't show the PC again.

In the past, unplugging the Mac, returned the PC to to be seen.

How to make my PC visible again?

Answer (score 0):

Some monitors have an autoscan inputs setting = ON it cycles between inputs looking for one that is active, OFF it doesn't.

Comment: mine had "auto select", but I see it works only with Mac on DVI. no PC with VGA